# How to pass multiple selected values to controller?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have converted the kendo dropdownlist into kendo multiselect. I wanted to pass multiple selected values to the controller.

Dropdownlist contains:

1. D-UDMS-TMA Data Mgmt System
2. U-TDMS-SMA Mgmt System

The below is my code:

```
$("#btnSendFlow").click(function () {

            debugger;

            var FlowData_array = [];

            //var ROLECODE = $("#DDRolecode").val().trim();---For dropdownlist output: "D"
            var ROLECODE = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect").value();//added by chetan for multiselect output: "D" "U"

            // var MPID = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoDropDownList").text().split('-');---for dropdownlist output: (3)["D","UDMS","TMA Data Mgmt System"]

            var control = $("#DDRolecode").data("kendoMultiSelect");
            var selectedDataItems = control.dataItems();

            //// create an array that only contains the selected ids
            var MPID = [];
            $(selectedDataItems).each(function () {
                MPID.push(this.Name.split('-')); // you can access any property on your model here
            });
            console.log(MPID);

            //
            output for MPID while debugging:
            (3)["D","UDMS","TMA Data Mgmt System"] which is 0: Array(3)
                                                              0: "D"
                                                              1: "UDMS"
                                                              2: "TMA Data Management Ltd"
                                                              length: 3
            (3)["U","TDMS","SMA Mgmt System"] which is 1: Array(3)
                                                          0: "M"
                                                          1: "BMET"
                                                          2: "Bglobal NHH MOP"
                                                              length: 3

            length:2
            //
        .....
        .....

         MstHeaderData = {
            REG_ID: $("#hfRegid").val(),
            DataFlow_ID: $("#DDDataFlow").val(),
            RoleCode: ROLECODE,//How to to do for the multiselect values.
            //RoleCode: ROLECODE.trim(),//for dropdownlist
           // MPID: MPID[1] //for dropdownlist
            MPID: MPID// How to do for the multiselect values
        }
        }
```

Commented lines is for Dropdownlist.

I am passing the mutiple(selected ie. Rolecode and MPID) values to the controller's Headerdetails.

The below is my Controller call:

```
 public ActionResult SaveSendFlowDetails(Temp_Flow_Generation_Item[] SSFD,HeaderDetails HeaderDetails, FormCollection form)
         {
         ....
         .....
         }
```

Class file:

```
public class HeaderDetails
          {
        public int REG_ID { get; set; }
        public int DataFlow_ID { get; set; }
        public string RoleCode { get; set; }
        public string MPID { get; set; }
         }
```

Comment: What is this.Name, where does that come from?

Comment: @BrianMains Thats a multiselect Parametres id and name

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your model property `MPID` to:

```
public string[][] MPID { get; set; }
```

As your data is a string array of string arrays, aka string matrix.

Answer (score 1):

i have used the below code and it worked:

```
 for (i = 0; i < MPID.length; i++) {


            MstHeaderData = {
                REG_ID: $("#hfRegid").val(),
                DataFlow_ID: $("#DDDataFlow").val(),
                RoleCode: MPID[i][0],
                //RoleCode: ROLECODE.trim(),
                // MPID: MPID[1]
                MPID: MPID[i][1]
            }


            var url = '@Url.Action("SaveSendFlowDetails", "FlowGenerator")';
            .....
            .....
}
```